# Generate schema for multiple filters in one pass

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**PROBLEM**
i amusing spark `1.5.0`. I have an RDD of different json string objects called `events`. Each json object has a field `type`. I want to create a different data-frame for each value of the `type` field. Then I want to generate the schema for each of the dataframes (df.printSchema()).

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "type": "x"}
{"a": 1, "c": 2, "type": "x"}
{"c": 1, "d": 2, "type": "y"}
{"d": 1, "e": 2, "type": "y"}
```

So my schema should look something like:

```
for type "x":
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c: string (nullable = true)

for type "y":
 root
 |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d: string (nullable = true)
 |-- e: string (nullable = true)
```

**What I tried:**

```
final String[] event_types = {"x", "y"};

for (final String event_type: event_types) {
    JavaRDD<String> filtered_events = events.filter(
        new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String s) {
                String event_type_t = null;
                try {
                    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(s);
                    event_type_t = json_data.getString("type").toString();
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (event_type.equalsIgnoreCase(event_type_t)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    );

    DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().option("header", "true").json(filtered_events);
    System.out.println(event_type);
    df.printSchema();

}
```

**ISSUES WITH EXIStiNG SOLUTION**
It runs for multiple passes for each filter. If there are multiple event types then it takes a lot of time to process. I'd like to do it in a single pass.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the most expensive part is actually a JSON parsing. It makes sense to push it outside filtering logic. Using Scala:

```scala
val events: RDD[String] = ???
val event_types = List("x", "y")
val df: DataFrame  = sqlContext.read.json(events)

val dfs = event_types.map(t => (t -> df.where($"type" <=> t))).toMap
```